# How to cross compile Tesseractocr for ARM Beagle Bone

Tags: embedded, ocr, tesseract, beagleboard

I'm looking for cross compiling Tesseract-ocr for ARM (Beagle Bone), is this possible? Theres a tutorial about this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use Buildroot to do this. Please add Tesseract package according to this manual: http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_autotools_based_packages

See this article for source code directory override mechanism: http://free-electrons.com/blog/buildroot-2011-11/